# Want my nav be responsively inline centered under logo

Tags: html, css

Got a logo:

```
 <div class="logo"></div>
```

And some navigation:

```
<ul class="bar">
       <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want my nav be under logo on mobile phones. I have got my logo centered but i don't know how to center my nav under logo.

Here's CSS:

```
.bar {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 9%;
  top: -60px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', sans-serif;
 }

.bar li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to define rules for mobile phones only:

```css
@media (max-width: 480px) {
.bar {
  //paste any mobile code here
}
                
.bar li {
  //paste any mobile code here
}
}
.bar {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  right: 9%;
  top: -60px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', sans-serif;
}

.bar li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo"></div>
<ul class="bar">
  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, but i don't know how to responsively center my list under logo.

Comment: use `posititon: relative` and define the position with pixels

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Media Queries. And apply your properties, in my case I am using `screen width <= 767px`.

Like:

```
/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .bar {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    right: auto;
  }

  .bar li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

Have a look at the snippet below:

```css
.logo {
  float: left;
  background: #eee;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bar {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  right: 9%;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-family: 'Coming Soon', sans-serif;
 }

.bar li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left: 60px;
}

/* On Mobiles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .logo {
    float: none;
  }
  
  .bar {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    right: auto;
  }
  
  .bar li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">Logo</div>
<ul class="bar">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @StanislavSosiak Hope this answer solves your problem, let me know if there is something that didn't works for you.